# How can I monitor the number of user password reset requests?

Tags: users, nodes

I would like to keep track of the number of times users request that their password be reset to make sure that users are able to reset their password successfully.  I am getting reports a couple of times a month that users are experiencing difficulty resetting their passwords; to see how common this is, I want to see if users are requesting their password be reset several times in a row (within the same day).

To do this, I was thinking of e-mailing myself every time a user requests that their password be reset.  My first instinct was to do this with Rules, but there is no Event like "When a user requests that their password be reset."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note, in [user_pass_submit](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.pages.inc/function/user_pass_submit/7)

```
watchdog('user', 'Password reset instructions mailed to %name at %email.', array('%name' => $account->name, '%email' => $account->mail));
```

There's already a watchdog log entry created when the user requests a password reset.

Perhaps you can simply monitor the watchdog log at

Admin > Reports > Recent log entries?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that.  With the watchdog entry, I can use the Logging and Alerts module to get myself an e-mail. http://drupal.org/project/logging_alerts

Comment: This is indeed the easiest way.